# list items are hiding in navigation bar on reducing window size

Tags: html, materialize

list items are hiding in navigation bar on reducing window size. I am using materializecss. How to avoid list items from hiding in navigation bar.

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo right">Logo</a>
      <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="python.html">PYTHON</a></li>
        <li><a href="java.html">JAVA</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript.html">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
        <li><a href="webdev.html">WEB DEV</a></li>
        <li><a href="android.html">ANDROID</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't know materializecss, but most likely you just have to erase the class `hide-on-med-and-down` from your `ul` element

Answer (score 0):

I think your `<li>` may collide with `<nav>` bar `CSS`. You can adjust the list pixel. I had this experience in bootstrap. You should open chrome web developer tool and check out for each window size both (mobile,desktop) view and check the list positions, variations in the background.you can easily find the bug.

Comment: My problem is solved after erasing the class `hide-on-med-and-down` from my `ul` element.